# Python property() returning unlisted field?

Tags: python, django

The code I'm looking at is from `django.contrib.auth.models.User`

```
def _get_message_set(self):
    import warnings
    warnings.warn('The user messaging API is deprecated. Please update'
                  ' your code to use the new messages framework.',
                  category=DeprecationWarning)
    return self.**_message_set**
message_set = property(_get_message_set)
```

--where the devil is this `_message_set` field?

I suspect something of the automatic sort is happening here, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Somewhere else. Did you check `__init__` for starters?

Comment: Which Django version is this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python, an attribute of an object does not need to be declared. In your case, it's set up in the constructor of the superclass `models.Model`.

Note that the internal attribute is prefixed with an underscore, whereas the external one (which happens to be a property) lacks one.

Comment: It would appear that I need to back up a few steps to acquaint myself better with Python fundamentals.  Are this module's patterns consistent with Python's current best practices?

Comment: @Withnail Well, this code excerpt definitely is, properties are exactly meant for something like this. However, bear in mind that the superclass - models.Model - is somewhat strange, since it dynamically constructs attributes. For someone new to Python, I wouldn't recommend reading it. And quite frankly, `models.Model` looks pretty hackish.

Comment: Django models are using **metaclasses** for this.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/what-is-a-metaclass-in-python/100146#100146 and https://bitbucket.org/django/django/src/de1ab1d6db7c/django/db/models/base.py#cl-26

Comment: This makes me feel better as the previous Python examples seemed easily readable and intuitive, while this Django module rather confused me.

Answer (score 1):

from [django.contrib.auth.models](https://bitbucket.org/django/django/src/de1ab1d6db7c/django/contrib/auth/models.py#cl-397):

```
class Message(models.Model):
    """
    The message system is a lightweight way to queue messages for given
    users. A message is associated with a User instance (so it is only
    applicable for registered users). There's no concept of expiration or
    timestamps. Messages are created by the Django admin after successful
    actions. For example, "The poll Foo was created successfully." is a
    message.
    """
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='_message_set')
    message = models.TextField(_('message'))

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.message
```